# How to prove UG is sound?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I want to show  that the PL is sound for the set of rules    $ S=\{P,T,C,US,UG,E \} $

That is, if $\Gamma \vdash_s \phi$, then $\Gamma \vDash \phi$

And I have already proved it except for UG

If $ \phi$ occurred in k+1 by UG, then there is $\phi (\alpha/\beta)$ in 1 < $ \mathcal l$  < k.

And by induction hypothesis, $\Gamma \vDash \phi (\alpha/\beta)$

My textbook, Benson mates, remains for me to show that for any  fomula $\phi $ and variable $\alpha$, if $\Gamma \vDash\phi(\alpha/\beta)$ and $\beta$ did't ocure above then $\Gamma \vDash (\forall \alpha)\phi$

And I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: This is standard textbook stuff! Go the library and look how other intro. textbooks handle it. (As a general point, it is always a very good idea to back up your main textbook for a class by consulting another book or two -- seeing a slightly different presentation can only help your understanding, and help develop a sense of what are the really key ideas and what are just local features of one particular way of presenting those ideas.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Ref to :

- Benson Mates, [Elementary Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=IK4sn97yA04C) (2nd edition - 1972).

Assume not, i.e. $\Gamma \nvDash (\forall \alpha)\phi$.

This means that there is an *interpretation* $\mathfrak I$ satisfying all sentences of $\Gamma$ which does not satisfy $(\forall \alpha)\phi$.

We need the details of the "semantical specifications" used in the textbook : see page 60.

Saying that $\mathfrak I \nvDash (\forall \alpha)\phi$ means that for some constant $\beta$ :

> $\mathfrak I' \nvDash \phi(\alpha / \beta)$

for some $\beta$-variant of $\mathfrak I$.

This contradicts the fact that $\mathfrak I \vDash \phi(\alpha/ \beta)$.

Why so ? Here is the "tricky point" of the proof that needs the proviso : $\beta$ does not occur in any sentences in $\Gamma$.

We have to reacall that a $\beta$-variant of $\mathfrak I$ differ from $\mathfrak I$ only on the value assigned to $\beta$; but $\beta$ does not occur in $\Gamma$.

Thus, if $\mathfrak I$ satisfy $\Gamma$, also any $\beta$-variant of $\mathfrak I$ must satisfy $\Gamma$.